# SQL Server: How to check if a WORKLAD GROUP and a RESOURCE POOL exists

Tags: sql-server-2016

In my SQL script, I want to drop a "WORKLOAD GROUP" and a "RESOURCE POOL", but it might be that they do not exist. How can I check?

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: You are looking for how to conditionally execute sql statements.

Comment: Yes, but these seems to be special ones. I can check if a function or a table exist but I do not found how to check if a resource pool or workload group exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution from another forum:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.resource_governor_resource_pools WHERE name = N'MyPool')
  DROP RESOURCE POOL MyPool
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.resource_governor_workload_groups WHERE name = N'MyGroup')  DROP WORKLOAD GROUP  MyGroup  GO
```